# Correcting a Torah with a marker

Tags: halacha, safrus

About a month ago, a sofer corrected a mistake in one of our shul's Torah scrolls.

I found the mistake while reading the end of parshat *Masei*. There was an incorrect letter that changed the meaning of the word. The letter should have been a *taf* but was actually written as a *heh*. To make the correction, a sofer just needs to draw a line between the top of the *heh* and the bottom and it becomes a *taf*.

When the sofer came, he corrected it using a marker. (Yes, it had sta"m ink.) I didn't have time to ask the sofer about the halachot of using a marker. I understoof that Torah scrolls need to be written using a quill / reed.

Is the halacha more lenient when making a correction in that one may use a marker for corrections? Are there certain types of corrections that allow using a marker? For example, can it be used only when correcting a wrong letter such as I described above, or can one use a marker even if he has to erase a letter and write a new one? What if he has to add a missing letter?

Comment: The Rama (YD 271:7) says explicitly you shouldn't use a feather/quill. Where did you hear that a Torah needs a feather/quill??

Comment: @DoubleAA I've seen every sofer use a quill. I'll look at your source.

Comment: The traditional implement is actually a reed (that's what [the Greek word "kulmus/kulmi" means](https://translate.google.com/?source=osdd#en/el/reed) as well as the Arabic cognate [Qalam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qalam)). The Talmud in a number of places praises reeds for having been chosen to write Torahs with (eg. Taanit 20b). I don't know much about the physics of ink flow in markers, but their's certainly no reason to use a bird feather/quill (other than perhaps convenience).

Comment: I have a reason to believe that if he used marker it was kosher and "okeyd" marker :) 

For example people still think that Mezuzot are written with quill :)

Comment: According to [this](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/sanhedrin/halachah/sn-hl-106.htm) the Rema says "some say" don't use a feather, and others mentioned there say it's because a feather quill engraves.  (I haven't seen the original Rema; I'm just reporting what I found while looking for more on the subject.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Gemara ( Taanis 20a) mentions that the reed was rewarded - because it's pliable and "easy going" and is used for writing a Sefer Torah.

I've seen people do that. (Sefardim, as a matter of fact)

However, as the R' Ganzfried writes in [Keset haSofer (2:16)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7521&st=%D7%A7%D7%A0%D7%94&pgnum=11&hilite=), this causes very uneven writing, as the reed needs to be sharpened every few words.

So  - he writes in the footnote - we write with a  quill or metal pen which can last *forever*. (I once wrote the entire Sefer Devarim without sharpening it.)

Nowadays metal quills are all the rage - though some people prefer not to write the Book of Life using metal, the *material of death*. (Can't find a source for that right now).

Bottom line: There's no Halachic why reason not to use a marker when writing or correcting a Sefer Torah. (You may have the *metal* issue, but that's a not Halachic, per se.)

Comment: All your discussion is about the material of the nib. None of it indicates that a marker, which is a wholly different physical delivery system for ink, would be valid.

Comment: @Double AA can you explain why the nib would have to be rigid and not soft? or some other parameter for the "delivery system" required?

Comment: @heshy I don't have a good answer to that, but a lot of people seem to think there are requirements and therefore invalidate silk screening for Torahs. How is a marker different from a silk screen? I don't know much about the physics of ink flow through the felt tip but I'm guessing it's a fine mesh and pressure on contact pulls ink through using some sort of cohesion. A reed pen on the other hand just works on gravity breaking the adhesion to the read as you split the tip

Comment: @DoubleAA i understood that silk screen is more a problem of lishma, not applicator. the question would be the same if you found a way to use a solid applicator. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @heshy what could possibly be wrong with the Lishmah? The guy says aloud before he writes 'i am writing this for the sake of a Torah scroll' just like any other Sofer does.

Comment: @heshy - I found this article - http://www.hakirah.org/Vol19Kleinhendler.pdf - that makes a great case for silk-screening. Goes against _everything we've been taught_ (i.e. our gut feelings and emotions) but presents their case very well.

Comment: You can hear the _other side_ at https://www.ou.org/torah/gemara/daf-yomi/daf-in-halacha/silkscreen-sefer-torah/ - around 18" he starts discussing "the real issues". Summary: 1. We have always used a quill/writing instrument. 2. Sirtut - which seems to be the only "real" issue they have come up with. According to some poskim, the sirtut has to HELP the writing and not just be in place. (3. Kesidron for Mezuza and Tefilin).